# Express priority for multiple matching rules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs

I have a babel server which i am configuring through express

I would like that my static files are served statically and hence i added the following rules:

```
app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.get(/.*\.(png|jpg|js|css)$/, express.static('public'));
```

However i also want that the page is loaded appropriately on refresh / direct link access so i added the following rule

```
app.get('/*', function (request, response) { // This wildcard method handles all requests
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
});
```

However, now on page load, when the page is requesting my bundle.js the server is serving it the index.html file (even though it is caught by the previous rule for static files). I assume that this is the case as it is prioritising in some manner the `/*` rule. How can i eliminate the static files from that rule?

Full file for context:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import session from 'express-session';

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

// we use helmet to disable typically unsafe operations
app.use(helmet());

// COOKIE CONFIGURATION

// we do not use the default session cookie name
// this is done to avoid attackers from fingerprinting the server
// and targetting it accordingly
app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
    secret: 'sercret',
    name: 'name' // the name of the sesion ID cookie to set in the response and read from the request
}));

// ROUTE CONFIGURATION

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.get(/.*\.(png|jpg|js|css)$/, express.static('public'));

app.get('/*', function (request, response) { // This wildcard method handles all requests
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is now listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: The routes are prioritised according to the order of their definition. Did you define the route for `/*` *after* the static handler?

Comment: yes. they are defined in the order of the question

Comment: added full file for visibility

Comment: directory structure ? try `app.use(express.static('public'));`

Answer (score 1):

RegExp is not a valid route accordingly to [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L45) and [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/blob/master/index.js#L45) source. And update '/' route:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: Even if so, `GET /bundle.js`, would be caught by `app.use('/', express.static('public'))`, taking into account that `bundle.js` exists in `public`. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @SergeyLapin I think, that '/' is works for the root url only.

Comment: According to express api http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#path-examples It can be a regex. And that regex matches anything that ends in .png .jpg .js .css

Comment: @mangusbrother Can you check if it works with`app.get(/.*\.(png|jpg|js|css)$/, express.static('public'))` middleware only?

Comment: without the '/' path (hence leaving the regex and the /* ones there) my pages still load if accessed through / and then click through, but if i access a subpage directly (or refresh) it still gives the same error